# Сокращение слова "упражнение"

Tags: сокращения

Можно ли слово "упражнение" сокращать до "у."?

Answer (score 1):

Безусловно, по правилам русского языка сокращать (и, само собой, ставить точку) после гласной и мягкого и твердого знаков нельзя. Сокращаются слова только **после согласной перед гласной**. Допустим, "страниц" - стр., а не "ст." и не "с.". Это не относится к устоявшимся сокращениям типа "о." (остров), "а.л." (авторский лист), которых не так много ("у."(упражение) к ним не относится), где гласная - первая буква слова. При "удвоенной согласной" сокращение происходит после первой буквы: грамматика *грам.*, стенный *стен.* Сравните: искусственный - либо *иск.*, либо *искусств.* (а не "искус.", или "искусс.", или "искусст.").  Поэтому верно будет *упр.*, *упражн.*, *упражнен.* (последние два варианта из-за относительно большого кол-ва букв менее употребительны, но имеют право на существование).

Answer (score 0):

Нет. По правилам русского языка нельзя сокращать слово так, чтобы сокращение заканчивалось на гласную. Сокращать можно "уп." или "упр."